# Visual Studio Update 4 crashes after startup screen

Tags: visual-studio-2013, crash

When I open "Visual Studio 2013 Update 4", it will show the following message

> An exception was thrown by a TaskScheduler.

I have searched the internet for solutions, but all proposed solutions suggest `/safemode` or `repair`. I have tried both ways and they both didn't work out.

I am pretty frustrated right now. Can you please provide a solution.

Comment: Clarified the question. Added formatting. Reformulated unclear phrasing.

Comment: update to the update 5 and look if it now works